# Удаление сообщения из сложного JS объекта

Tags: javascript, lodash

Есть чатик, сообщения хранятся в такой структуре:

```js
{
  chat: {
     entities: {
        chats: {
          byUserId: {
            65: [
              {id: 1, time: 1505758770, text: "1", status: "sent"},
              {id: 2, time: 1505758771, text: "2", status: "sent"},
              {id: 3, time: 1505758771, text: "3", status: "sent"}
            ]
          }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Тут `65` этой `id` чата (юзера). В нем хранятся объекты сообщений.

Проблема: необходимо реализовать удаление сообщений, для этого с этой структуры необходимо удалить сообщение по id. `userId` и `id` сообщения мы знаем, по сути нужно пробежаться по масиву сообщений и оставить все КРОМЕ сообщения с id удаленного.

Я пробовал вот так с помощью lodash, но не до конца:

```js
_.reduce(Object.keys(test.chat.entities.chats.byUserId[userId]), (result, key) => {
          if (test.chat.entities.chats.byUserId[userId][key].id !== id) {
            result[userId] = [
              test.chat.entities.chats.byUserId[userId][key]
            ]
          }
          return result;
}, {});
```

Реализация лучше с помощью `lodash`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если один раз взять и почитать внимательно [доку](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#update), то можно открыть для себя удивительные вещи

```
_.update(
    data,
    ['chat', 'entities', 'chats', 'byUserId', userId],
    messages => _.reject(messages, { id })
)
```

Comment: А можно ссылку на доку?

Comment: @Air обновил ответ

Comment: Благодарю!!!!!!

Answer (score 4):

Как-то так:

```js
let data = {
  chat: {
     entities: {
        chats: {
          byUserId: {
            65: [
              {id: 1, time: 1505758770, text: "1", status: "sent"},
              {id: 2, time: 1505758771, text: "2", status: "sent"},
              {id: 3, time: 1505758771, text: "3", status: "sent"}
            ]
          }
        }
     }
  }
}
let userId = 65;
let msgId = 2;
data.chat.entities.chats.byUserId[userId] = data.chat.entities.chats.byUserId[userId].filter(msg => msg.id != msgId);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: `filter` да понятно, но все же хотелось бы с помощью `lodash`

Comment: Тогда уберите строчку из вопроса "Реализация не обязательно через lodash". Потому что я ориентировался на нее.